# ValueError: signature error: Cannot decompress Edwards point

Tags: python, error, keypair

I use [example in docs solana for python](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-generate-a-mnemonic-phrase)

```
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from mnemonic import Mnemonic

mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
words = mnemo.generate(strength=256)
seed = mnemo.to_seed(words)
keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(seed)
print("Created Keypair with Public Key: {}".format(keypair.pubkey()))
```

When I generate a key pair I often get the error "ValueError: signature error: Cannot decompress Edwards point":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "****", line 247, in <module>
    keypair = Keypair.from_bytes(seed)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: signature error: Cannot decompress Edwards point

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

This is a mistake in the cookbook. It's passing in a seed to `from_bytes`, when there's already a `Keypair.from_seed` implementation. Use that instead, ie:

```
mnemo = Mnemonic("english")
words = mnemo.generate(strength=256)
seed = mnemo.to_seed(words)
keypair = Keypair.from_seed(seed[:32])
```

`from_bytes` won't always work because the keypair provided may not correspond to a point on the curve.

Comment: this action return an error: `keypair = Keypair.from_seed(seed)   ValueError: expected a sequence of length 32 (got 64)`

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. I've edited my answer

Comment: great answer, bro